# Is the language below not decidable , if yes , it is then R.E ?

Tags: turing-machines, undecidability, semi-decidability

I am given a Turing machine M as input  and i have to find  out  if this language  below  decidable  and  if not  is it then in this case  recursively enumerable .

$$L=\\\{<M>  \mid \text{ is there $w_1,w_2$ for M so that M for both halts but  with  different results }\}$$

Somehow i ended up finding that the language is not decidable nor R.E .

if you have an other point of view ,  can you  then please give me some  hints.

Comment: How is "...$M$ for both halts but with different results" interpreted?  Is it "If $M(w_1)$ and $M(w_2)$ halt then $M(w_1) \neq M(w_2)$" or "$M(w_1)$ halts AND $M(w_2)$ halts AND $M(w_1) \neq M(w_2)$"?

Comment: like  for example  after  halting ,$w_1$ ist accepted and $w_2$ is not